# Potential security issues of this user form

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xss, sql-injection

I'm trying to create a secure sign up form, this is just the first few fields there are going to be about another dozen or so more but that's irrelevant. I'm a bit security concious and I am wondering if the following code is sufficiantly protected against XSS and SQL Injections.

- I'm using htmlentities as I am displaying some of the user input back to the user if any entries are wrong.
- I believe I've used prepared statements correctly.
- I've included the start of the form just to show that since I'm posting to self htmlentities are needed.

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $emailrepeat = htmlentities($_POST['emailrepeat'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $password = htmlentities($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  $passwordrepeat = htmlentities($_POST['passwordrepeat'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');



  if (empty($firstname)) 
  {   
      $fnError = "Please Enter Your First Name";
  }
  if (empty($lastname)) 
  {
      $lnError = "Please Enter Your Last Name";
  }


  $getEmail = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
  $getEmail->bind_param('s', $email);
  $getEmail->execute();
  $getEmail->store_result();
  $countRows = $getEmail->num_rows;
  if ($countRows > 0) 
  {
      $emError = "Email Address Already Exists";
      $countRows = 0;
  }



  else if (empty($email)) 
  {
  $emError = "Please Enter an Email Address";
  }
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
  {
  $emError = "Invalid Email Address";
  }
  else if ($email != $emailrepeat)
  {
      $emError = "Emails do not match";
  }

  if (empty($password)) 
  {
      $pwError = "Please Enter a Password";
  }
  else if (strlen($password)<6)
  {
      $pwError = "Password must be atleast 6 characters";
  }
  else if ($password != $passwordrepeat)
  {
      $pwError = "Emails do not match";
  }

  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
  {

      if ($password == $passwordrepeat and !empty($password) and strlen($password)>5)
      {
          $pwhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));

          if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
          {
              $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $pwhash);
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->close();
          }


      }
  }
  }

  <form id="addnewuser" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);    ?>" method="POST"> 
  </form>
  ```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. I don't see any major issues. In addition to MonkeyZeus's concern below, is there any particular reason why you chose `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` instead of `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`? Right now they're equivalent, but remember, `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. Just something to consider...

Comment: @IanDrake I might be misunderstanding something but If `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is `Algorithm1024` this week and next week it is `Algorithm2048` then wouldn't the users from the first week no longer be able to log in?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Based on my understanding, `password_hash()` always encodes the algorithm info in the resulting hash, so `password_verify()` always knows how to verify it. The docs say, "The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information." This is mentioned on the docs page for both functions.

Comment: @IanDrake Clearly a misunderstanding on my part; sometimes we all need a good RTFM moment ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response. The reason I used BCRYPT over DEFAULT was from, what I have read was the better option. But after reading your comment and a quick search you are right. Only question before I switch them round is currently the server I'm using is running PHP 5.3.10 and I've had to use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat to use password_hash(). Is PASSWORD_DEFAULT still the way forward?

Comment: @MattM Generally speaking, yes, I would go with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT`. Unless your system has some kind of special requirements, it will help make your code more "future-proof". This philosophy is reiterated by this comment on the docs page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#112495. Also, I have used that library before and I can confirm that it makes the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` constant available to use, so I don't think that's an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Kudos for using prepared statements!**

**2. Read below**

Overall this looks quite good from a security standpoint but you are most certainly going to run into issues by using `htmlentities()` everywhere.

With your logic, if I want to use a password like `ThisIsSo<Secu>r` then your code is going to convert it to it to `ThisIsSo&lt;Secu&gt;r` so it will be impossible for me to login to your website unless you are also using `htmlentities()` on the login page's username/password.

When saving user data to your database you should always maintain the integrity of what the user typed and implement the proper escaping upon echo'ing the data. The exception to this would be something like the CKEditor; but the editor takes care of the escaping for you.

To illustrate this better you will want to use `htmlentities()` like this:

```
<div class="welcome-banner">Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($row['firstname']); ?>!</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<h3>Editing Your Profile</h3>
<label>First Name</label><br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['firstname']); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks, good advice. I did think about this regarding the password. I'm not feeding any password back to the user so do I need any escaping on the password field?

Comment: Ok, I've changed my code so the user input is fed directly into the prepared statement and I'm only escaping what is fed back into the input fields.

Comment: Good answer MonkeyZeus. Although you should add that there should be a primary key on `$email` otherwise there's a race condition where two users could be created the same if done quickly enough (@MattM).

Comment: @SilverlightFox Great advice! but maybe OP is already doing that? I think you should ask him by commenting on the question. I don't think OP gets notification of comments on answers unless they get tagged.

Comment: I tagged him too at the end ;)

Comment: I've set up a user ID field as the primary key on AI. This should solve that problem? For the second lot of data (mentioned but not in my original code) that will go into a different table I'll be saving the ID (which will effectively be the foreign key) by using mysqli_insert_id().This will also have its own AI primary key. @SilverlightFox

Comment: @MattM: What do you mean by Al?

Comment: Auto Increment @SilverlightFox

Comment: @MattM You need some sort of unique key on email address.

Comment: Yes I do, I also need to confirm email doesn't exist before entering it into the database! Missed that. I was following my own error codes! @SilverlightFox

Comment: Make sure you pass the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to `htmlentities()` if you're using it in an HTML attribute context.